# What is considered a separate ASP.NET app?

Tags: asp.net

Doesn't all ASP.NET apps need to be isolated to different virual directories to run as a separate app?  If not, wouldn't there be a problem with the root web.config and the BIN folder?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, each ASP.NET app will have its own virtual directory.

Answer (score 0):

"virtual directory" is not the deciding factor.  ASP.Net apps can live in regular folders as well.  The important part is whether or not you have the folder set as an application in IIS.  The terminology is different depending on your IIS version.  IIS 7 has a "Convert to application" menu item, but back in IIS 4 it was a property on the isolation level.